# Bad vampire movie about people trying to escape to a vampire-free "new earth"

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a title to a VHS vampire movie from the 80s or early 90s in the US that is set in a world overrun by vampires.

There is a small group of survivors that just so happen to have a scientist that created a gateway to a "new earth" without vampires. Unknown to the scientist, however, the vampire "queen" had apparently snuck in and went through ahead of the group (looking to start over in another world too. The opening scene starts with a fat guy in a beret running down an alley chased by 2 vamps who are unable to catch him (yes, yes ... was a very bad movie, but good for a laugh).
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My first thought on 'Bad vampire movie with world overrun by vampires'  was *Daybreakers* but the rest of the plot does not fit